# How do i get the value from JTextField in java that was created dynamically through a JLabel click

Tags: java, jtextfield

I am creating a JTextField everytime a label is clicked. My problem is to get the text inside those created textfields.

This is my code:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {    
    List<JTextField> mine = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    box = new JTextField();
    name = new JTextField();
    pnlPanel.add(box);
    pnlpanel.add(name);
    lay++;
    if (lay > 0) {
        box.setBounds(283, 145, 182, 27);
        name.setBounds(81, 145, 182, 27);
        mine.add(box);
    }
    GetData mydata = new GetData();
    mydata.doGetData();
    frame.repaint();
}
```

This is my code for getting the data inputted by the user, but it doesnt work:

```
public class GetData {
    public void doGetData(List<JTextField> myFields) {
        for (JTextField txt: myFields) {
        }
    }
}
```

How does I get the user input?

Comment: from where you want to get the text inside those JTextFields and do you know that there are no values yet inside them ?

Comment: You can use `box.getText()` to get the values from the textfields !

Comment: yes. Because the scene is like this: The user will hit a jLabel and then text box will be created for the user to typed in. Then after hitting that label, the user will be able to input the necessary data, and after clicking a button, all the text from the created textfields will be put into a variable which i will then save to my databse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to store the fields in some kind of way. I prefer to use an ArrayList, but (as mentioned by Klemens Morbe) there are many ways to that.

Here is a basic example, the output will appear in the console.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;


public class MoreAndMoreTextfields extends JFrame {

    // the panel, that we will add the visible fields to
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    // a collection of all fields, so that we can access them afterwards
    private Collection<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    public MoreAndMoreTextfields() {

        // basic window layout stuff
        setSize(400, 300);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        setContentPane(panel);

        // add label, that will create new input fields
        JLabel addInputLabel = new JLabel("click for more fields");
        addInputLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                JTextField textField = new JTextField();
                panel.add(textField);
                textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
                textFields.add(textField);
                revalidate();
            }
        });
        panel.add(addInputLabel);

        // add new label, that will print out contents
        JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel("click for contents");
        outputLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Contents of fields:");
                for (JTextField textField : textFields) {
                    System.out.println("  input:"+textField.getText());
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(outputLabel);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MoreAndMoreTextfields().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Youre welcome.PS: you should consider using "LayoutManagers", as I did in the example

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Answer (score 0):

For getting the text of the JTextField use `textfield.getText()`. 
You could save the JTextFields to a list `List<JTextField>` 
or iterate through the panels components`panel.getComponents()`. 
Aslo you could give every JTextField an id like this `textfield.setName("id");`.

Comment: Thanks for understanding me. I did textfield.getText(); but its not working its not giving me anything, please see my edited code above.